# How FFmpeg CRF works

Tags: ffmpeg

How FFmpeg `-CRF` works?

How do they decide the best quality of this specific second?

Will we get better results if I will split the file by seconds and encode each slice separately with `-CRF` and then join all the slices or would I will get the same/wors results and why?

Answer (score 0):

CRF stands for constant rate factor. “Constant” means it does actually make any decisions on rate control. It picks certain values for quantizing matrixes, and uses them no matter what the resulting bitrate it.

Splitting and jointing CRF files should result in the exact same video if the key frames are the same.

Comment: I meant if I will put on each slice different CRF value based on quality measures I will conduct and then join all the slices, is it will get me a better result overall?